# SQL Statement - Select from two tables, create column if secondary table has related record

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm posting here because I have not been able to find what I'm looking for, or even the correct keywords to search on.  If there are better answers that I was unable to find, please feel free to point me in that direction.

However I have two tables which Table 1 is the primary table, and I need to SELECT all records out of it and add an additional column in the SELECT that returns if any related records in Table 2.

I have boiled the problem down to the following and any help would be much appreciated.

- Table 1 has a many relationship to Table 2
- SELECT must return all rows from Table 1
- SELECT must have an additional column (preferably a BOOLEAN/INTEGER) column that represents if there are any related records in Table 2.
- SELECT must work in both Access and SQL Server

---

```
 TABLE 1
--------
GUID1 | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD
GUID2 | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD
GUID3 | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD

 TABLE 2
--------
GUID1 | TABLE 1 GUID | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD
GUID2 | TABLE 1 GUID | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD
GUID3 | TABLE 2 GUID | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD
GUID4 | TABLE 2 GUID | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD


SELECTED TABLE ( 1 JOINED ON TABLE 2 )
--------
GUID1 | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD | 1 (EXISTS IN TABLE 2)
GUID2 | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD | 1 (EXISTS IN TABLE 2)
GUID3 | DATA FIELD | DATA FIELD | 0 (DOES NOT EXISTS IN TABLE 2)
```

Comment: Seems like homework to me. I was too lazy to do mine, what makes you think I'll do yours? Please show us what you have already tried and decide if it's sql server or ms-access. Also, remove the Mictosoft tag. it's irrelevant.

Comment: Its not homework - I'm six years out and using SQL more than basic stuff.

Also its both - our application runs on either access or sql which is why I have it tagged as both.

Comment: Furthermore, the reason it looks like homework is that I have removed all the business logic out of the problem so it is generic enough for folks in the future.

Comment: Still you need to improve your question. you should know how to ask better question after almost 3 years in stackoverflow

Comment: Look at using count. An app that can run on either sql server or access scares me. I have a bad feeling it is ripe for sql injection since the way parameters work will be different.

Comment: How should it be improved?  I have removed all business logic, its generic, it clearly states the problem.  

The only thing is is missing is attempted solutions, however the post is rather long already and I did not want to clutter the initial question

Comment: Sean - its an MFC application that wraps on a local instance of SQL Server or Access.  No SQL injection worries here, its just a generic select that populates a grid view.  I have a count/group that I am going to use now because it presents more information to the user but was unsure if I should post it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a case statement to check if the data in the second table is null. Here is an example:

```
SELECT First.*, 
   CASE 
     WHEN Second.DATA3 IS NULL
     THEN 0
     ELSE 1
   END
FROM First
LEFT OUTER JOIN Second ON First.GUID1 = Second.GUID1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab17a/1

Comment: Thanks!  

I ended using a bit different solution, (using a count/group by) but this answers the question.

Comment: The question asked for a query which will run in both SQL Server and MS Access.  `CASE ... WHEN` is not supported in Access SQL.